# What is the correct way to check whether an android APK uses vpn service?

Tags: android, vpn

I am trying to determine whether an installed APK uses vpn service. I know this information is in the AndroidManifest. However I need to find this out programatically. I tried using the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) checkPermission API. And it works for permissions such as android.permission.INTERNET. But, how do I check for android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE? The above API does not seem to be the correct one to check for android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE. I noticed in the manifest that this permission is not found in the tag `uses-permission` but is instead found within the service tag:

```
<service android:name="com.xyz.VpnService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PackageManager` to retrieve the `ServiceInfo` for this service ([via `getServiceInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getServiceInfo%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29)), then look at the `permission` field of the `ServiceInfo` object.

Comment: When I tried constructing the ComponentName object from [packagename](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#packageName) and [classname](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#className) I keep getting PackageManager.NameNotFoundException. Am I passing in the correct class name?

Comment: @sunnybythesea: "Am I passing in the correct class name?" -- I have no idea. I cannot see your monitor from here, as it is turned the wrong way, and there's the curvature of the Earth and stuff... :-) Update your question with your code where you create the `ComponentName`, and paste in the stack trace with the exception.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance on this. Don't have access to the logs right now, but will update soon. I suspect that when constructing the ComponentName I need to pass in classname of service class and not ApplicationInfo.className string which I did. I'm trying to retrieve this information for 3rd party app and don't have access to service class name (or do I?). Alternatively, I tried to enumerate PackageInfo.services, but it returned null, as did PackageInfo.permissions. Yes I will share more data from logs soon :)